# Crop transform in WPF?

Tags: .net, wpf, layout, transform, margin

WPF allows to use subclasses of [`Transform`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.media.transform.aspx) to scale([`ScaleTransform`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.media.scaletransform.aspx)), rotate([`RotateTransform`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.media.rotatetransform.aspx)), skew ([`SkewTransform`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.media.skewtransform.aspx)) and so on any [`FrameworkElement`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.frameworkelement.aspx).

But I cannot see how to crop some [`FrameworkElement`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.frameworkelement.aspx) using these. Is there any way how to crop lets say a `Label` of width 30px so it will behave as if its width was 20px?

To be more exact: I want to do this before laying out so that the `Label` would be laid out as if its width was 20. But I want it to be rendered fully so the last 10 pixels will be rendered too (possibly overlapping other elements). How can I do this ?

Why do I need this ? I want to make [H.B.'s answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5796457/create-guitar-chords-editor-in-wpf-from-richtextbox/5797833#5797833) to my question [Create guitar chords editor in WPF](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5796457/create-guitar-chords-editor-in-wpf-from-richtextbox) to work with [kerning](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kerning).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a negative `Margin` on the label, e.g. `Margin="0,0,-10,0"` makes the Label 10 pixels shorter on the right, layout-wise. (To prevent overlap put it in a container and set `ClipToBounds="True"`)

Comment: H.B.: +1 This was the fastest good answer I ever got. This is also solution but what if I really wanted to make previous element `5` pixels shorter for layout system yet still render it fully? Instead of setting next element's margin `Margin="-5,0,0,0"`? Because that is the way how other editors (like `RichTextBox`) deal with kerning. I don't why they don't use something like margin to do it but there might be a problem when highlighting text and so on (when elements overlap each other).

Comment: I do not quite get your problem, if you set `Margin="0,0,-5,0"` on the previous item it should be shorter and still render unless you set clipping.

Answer (score 0):

My problem with H.B.'s solution was, that i can't bind only the top margin.

i use XAML like this to build kindof a round progressbar (an ellipse, that gets cropped at the top):

```
<Canvas Name="ProgressIndicator" Width="120" Height="{Binding ProgressIndicatorHeight}" ClipToBounds="True">
    <Ellipse Width="120" Canvas.Bottom="0" Height="120" Fill="#FF7090B7"/>
</Canvas>
```

When i change the height of the canvas, the top of the ellipse gets cropped (because it is aligned to the bottom of the canvas). if i aligned it to the top (default), it would be cropped on the bottom.

I use this construct inside a round icon to fill it up proportionaly to the progress.