# how do i remove space from richTextBox

Tags: c#, wpf, visual-studio, xaml

https://i.stack.imgur.com/zYpqd.png

how can i remove space? is there any property for this? or maybe i can do it only manually in xaml? here is all xaml:

```
<Window x:Class="WPFnotatnik.MainWindow"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    Title="MainWindow" Height="350" Width="525">
<Grid>
    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
        <RowDefinition/>
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>
    <Menu Grid.Row="0">
        <MenuItem Header="File"/>
        <MenuItem Header="Another"/>
    </Menu>
    <Grid x:Name="contentGrid" Grid.Row="1">
        <RichTextBox Name="richTextBox1" HorizontalContentAlignment="Left" />
    </Grid>
</Grid>
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [WPF: How to make RichTextBox look like TextBlock?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5820578/wpf-how-to-make-richtextbox-look-like-textblock)

Comment: Are you sure this is a space and not padding left of the control?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is works: Padding="**-4** 0 0 0"

```
<RichTextBox Name="richTextBox1"
                     HorizontalContentAlignment="Left"
                     Padding="-4 0 0 0" />
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried setting the `Margin=0` or `Padding = 0`? That might do the trick :)